# Custom Error Object with Apollo Server

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to use a custom error with [apollo-server](https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-server) and it seems that my custom error has a property (`code`) that isn't available from within `formatError`.

```
import ExtendableError from 'es6-error'

export default class MyError extends ExtendableError {
  constructor(args) {
    let code = Object.keys(args)[0]
    let message = Object.values(args)[0]
    super(message)
    this.code = code
  }
}
```

I have a simple error handler works something like this:

```
let INVALIDREQUEST = 'invalid request'
let e = new MyError({INVALIDREQUEST})
console.log(e.code) // => "INVALIDREQUEST"
```

I'm having trouble because when I log `error.code` from within `formatError` it's not available.

```
formatError: function (error) {
  console.log(error.code) // => undefined
  return error
}
```

How can I propagate custom properties (like `code`) of `error` from within `formatError`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because Apollo Server uses GraphQL.js, we can find the solution by digging deep there: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/44f315d1ff72ab32b794937fd11a7f8e792fd873/src/error/GraphQLError.js#L66-L69

Essentially, the GraphQL.js reference implementation catches any errors in your resolvers, and delivers them to the `formatError` function, but it wraps them in a special GraphQL-specific error object, with properties like `path`, `positions`, and `source`.

You can find the original error you threw from the resolver on the `originalError` field of the `error` object in `formatError`, like so:

```
formatError: function (error) {
  console.log(error.originalError.code)
  return error
}
```

Comment: why node log is different from graphiql? in graphiql i can see the states when i add in formaterror:  error.state = error.originalError; but in node console i see just: GraphQLError ( .. at locatedError ..)  path, positions, and source. can I see in the console on node, my state property?

Answer (score 5):

With Apollo, you can easily multiplex the errors array in the graphql response for both graphql errors AND custom errors that are machine readable using this package:

https://github.com/thebigredgeek/apollo-errors

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's enough. You can define error code (2 parameter), error message and any custom object in extensions (3 parameter)

```
     throw new ApolloError('User already exist',
                           'DUPLICATE',
                           { 'session': session })
```

Comment: Throwing ANY `ApolloeError` or a subclass thereof will always strip the message and insert `Unexpected error value: { extensions: { code: <your code> }}` instead of _actually just passing up the error or presenting the error as thrown._ The message is *always* omitted, which defeats the whole process of using ApolloError type if `formatError` always destroys what you actually want to throw.